# Trying to return a Users individual CKRecord Information - Swift, Cloudkit

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cloudkit

My code works fine with fetching record and returning them to my UITableview but the problem is it returns all the records in the Type. I have made users by saving them to the cloud via [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore). So every time the User logs in I want them to be able to see just their information (Fields in their [CKRecord](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord)) in the UITableView.

```
func fetch () {
    if userLoad(){
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "User", predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "username", ascending: false)]
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "type", ascending: false)]
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "hours", ascending: false)]
        database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (results,error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error" + error.debugDescription)
            } else {
                for results2 in results!{
                    self.trucks.append(results2)
                }
            }
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
                self.TableView.reloadData()
                self.TableView.isHidden = false

            })
            print(results!)
        }
    } else {
        print("no user currently available")
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return trucks.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
    }

    let cell = TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstTableCell") as! FirstTableCell

    if userLoad() {
        let truck = trucks[indexPath.row]
        cell.usernameLabel?.text = truck.value(forKey: "username") as? String
        cell.typeLabel?.text = truck.value(forKey: "type") as? String
        cell.hoursLabel?.text = truck.value(forKey: "hours") as? String
        return cell
    } else {
        print("no user")
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't show how you define 'predicate.'

Comment: let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

Comment: I don't know what the variable named database is.

Comment: let database = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

Comment: Also, trucks is an array of CKRecord - var trucks = [CKRecord]()

Comment: You are simply using a wrong type of database.  Use the private database.

Comment: I switched to a private database and the UItableview is still showing all the CKRecords in that type. Do you think it has something to do with the numberOfRowsInSection? I have it returning trucks.count which I'm thinking is returning all the CKRecords..

Comment: Work on security roles.

Comment: UPDATE** - So I creating multiple users under the same apple ID, which was why I could see all the CKRecords in that type in my UITableView. I created a new apple ID and made a user under the private database and couldn't see the other Users I made with my previous apple ID. You're a genius man! I appreciate it.